# How to reverse a singly linked list in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to reverse a single linked list with this code but its not working properly.The following code not works in that case when the size of list is two otherwise it works well.I cannot find error in this code and spent a lot of time on it.Please tell me whats wrong with this code?

```
void list::reverse()
{
    node *current = head;
    if (current->next != NULL)
    {
        node *move = current->next;
        while (move->next != NULL)
        {
            node *temp = move->next;
            move->next = current;
            if (current == head)
            {
                current->next = NULL;
            }
            current = move;
            move = temp;
        }
        if (move->next == NULL)
        {
            move->next = current;
            if (current == head)
            {
                current->next == NULL;
            }
            head = move;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you get to half way down your list, what do you think the value of next is?

Comment: What did you observe when inspecting your code with the debugger?

Comment: Control is not come on these if block statements in case when list size is two.

Comment: if (current == head)
            {
                current->next == NULL;
            }

Comment: The best way to debug pointer code is still pen(cil) and paper. Draw your list. Draw what happens. Compare to what should happen.

Comment: [related](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/45918/489).

Comment: Also, if you increase the warning level of your compiler, you should see the message "warning: statement has no effect" or something like that.

Comment: @studentweb `current->next == NULL;` is a NOP. Did you mean to write `current->next = NULL; `?

Answer (score 0):

You have:

A (== head) -> B -> C -> D

You want (?):

D (== head) -> C -> B -> A

I got lost in your algorithm completely, can't figure out how it would work, or how to fix it easily. Actually I have hard time to believe it works for longer lists. But too lazy to try.

Maybe try to understand this one (in pseudo C++), looks simpler to me?:

```
src = head;
reversed = nullptr;
while (nullptr != src) {
    // node to insert at the beginning of reversed list
    to_prepend = src;
    // iterate trough all nodes in normal direction
    src = src->next;
    // now insert the currently read node at the head of reversed list
    to_prepend->next = reversed;
    reversed = to_prepend;
}
head = reversed;
```

I didn't wrote code+debug, so can't guarantee correctness, but it should work like this:

A (== head) -> B -> C -> D

1. current: A, reversed null, current updated to B (A->B), A->reversed(nullptr), reversed=A
2. current: B, reversed A, current to C (B->C), B->reversed(A), reversed=B
3. current: C, reversed B->A, current to D, C->reversed(B), reversed=C
4. current: D, reversed C->B->A, current to nullptr, D->reversed(C), reversed=D
5. current: nullptr: exit while
6. head = reversed (= D->C->B->A->nullptr).

---

Also in your code the:

`current->next == NULL;` is boolean expression, throwing the result away, not doing anything.

Comment: You can try to "draw" the same steps as me for your code, maybe that will help you understand what's happening with your code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure that if you draw all the process you'll find an easy solution to your goal